# Returning Observable based on callback

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I try to adjust a working example from ngx-chips to my needs. This is how the onRemoving method example looks like:

```
public onRemoving(tag: TagModel): Observable<TagModel> {
        const confirm = window.confirm('Do you really want to remove this tag?');
        return Observable
            .of(tag)
            .filter(() => confirm);
    }
```

Now instead of `windows.confirm` I want to use a custom component that has a `AskQuestion` method with the following signatur:

```
AskQuestion(question: string, yesCallback: () => void, noCallback?: () => void): void {
```

So now I have  multiple callbacks but the ngx-chips components expect that I return an observable. I tried to convert the callback to an observable using the `bindCallback` method:

```
 public onRemoving(tag: TagModel): Observable<TagModel> {

    const choiceCallback = (choice: boolean): TagModel=> {
      if (choice)
        return tag;
    };

    this.questionService.AskQuestion("Remove item?", () => choiceCallback(true), () => choiceCallback(false))

    return Observable.bindCallback(choiceCallback);
  }
```

But it looks like I am doing it wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `bindCallback()` reads:

> Give it a function f of type f(x, callback) and it will return a function g that when called as g(x) will output an Observable.

And your usage does not fit this description. `choiceCallback()` does not return a function that returns an observable.

Use an Observable constructor instead:

```js
public onRemoving(tag: TagModel): Observable <TagModel> {

  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const choiceCallback = (choice: boolean) => {
      if (choice) {
        observer.next(tag);
      }
      observer.complete();
    };

    this.questionService.AskQuestion("Remove item?", () => choiceCallback(true), () => choiceCallback(false));
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect André, thank you very much. You only missed the return statements within the choiceCallback.

Comment: no return statement on purpose. if `choice === true`, when post an item and complete, when `false` just complete.

Comment: You are right but then I have to remove the `:TagModel` return declaration, otherwise I get the following error: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` Anyhow, it works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% familiar with this stack, but as far as I could see, looks like `bindCallback` returns a function which returns an `Observable` ([docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback)).

So maybe you need to call it to get an observable and use it on your return statement?
Since in your function signature says it would return an Observable type.

You could try to replace the return statement by:
`return Observable.bindCallback(choiceCallback)()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately that doesn't work but Andrè answered my question.